# Как получить длину массива, который является аргументом делегата?

Tags: c#

Есть класс Dereviative, в котором я хочу сделать проверку длины массива, который является аргументом функции.
Объявление Делегата в классе Dereviative:

```
public delegate double functionToDereviate(double[] x);
```

Потом я хочу использовать этот делегат как аргумент статической функции класса Dereviative:

```
 public static double takeDereviative(
           functionToDereviate func,
           double[] argumentForFunc,
           int argumentForDereviation,
           double step)
```

а в этом методе хочу проверить длину масива x

Я застрял на таком:

```
func.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.
```

А куда дальше копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверка длины массива `w` -- [`w.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Для вашего делегата аргументов может быть массив *любой* длины, так что вопрос "какой длины массив принимает делегат" лишён смысла.

В C# нету отдельного типа, например, "массив из 5 элементов типа `int`", есть лишь тип "массив элементов типа `int`". Количество элементов -- свойство времени выполнения объекта массива (которое можно опросить при помощи упомянутого свойства `Length`.)

Comment: Разве нету метода получить длину  такого массива во время выполнения программы?

Comment: @Demonoid67: Какого массива? Который _фактически_ передан или который _может быть_ передан? Почему `Length` не подходит?

Comment: ясно =) Спасибо!

Comment: Мда...только что понял абсурдность своего вопроса!

Comment: @Demonoid67: пожалуйста! Хорошо, что разобрались.

Comment: Тыц, и теперь у @VladD'а 10К )))

Comment: @SilverIce: спасибо! У меня юбилей выходит :)